# Imported .sav file (SPSS) with variable coded 0 and 1

Tags: import, spss

When I import a .sav file (SPSS) into R, where a variable has been coded with 0 and 1, it reads in one variable as NA. I've encountered this with several .sav files that I imported into R. You would think it would read the 0 variable as NA, but it reverses the variables from the way they are described in an accompanying report. For example, for the variable sex, males (n=99)(coded 0) and females (n=110)(coded 1) in the report are reversed so that males (n=99) appears as a variable named Males, but females (n=110) are NA. In another dataset, the main grouping variables are A and B. Group A shows 0 and Group B shows 94, and NAs are 96 (all of group A) (the same reversal is occurring but I can't demonstrate that here). An explanation would be interesting, but my immediate problem is how to get the NAs into the other variable (or a new variable, for further analysis). I've created a small select of 2 columns and slice of 10 rows. I'm not sure how to create small dataframe for you here. This is the group variable with one other variable (MH0Q1):

group MH0Q1

```
2 <NA> <NA>
3 <NA> <NA>
4 <NA> <NA>
5 <NA> 1
6 B <NA>
7 B <NA>
8 B 2
8 B <NA>
9 B <NA>
10 B <NA>
11 B 2
```

The attributes of MH0Q1: 
    $ MH0Q1  : Named num  0 1 2
      .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "0" "1" "2"

Thanks

Comment: Never mind. I just found an R package that reads the data in correctly ('foreign'). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said how you are reading this sav file in R.  It might be that the problematic variable is categorical in the sav file and is being converted to an R factor differently than you expect.

Comment: When I used a package called "rio" I had the problem. With package "foreign it's ok. How would you determine the type of variable in the .sav file? Yes, everything is read in as a factor. Now I'm having a problem with another .sav file, where all values of one variable are NA, and there are four levels. Doesn't seem like it would be due to 0 and 1 coding. I may ask as a separate question.